# Is there a way to set Exchange server to overrule the full inbox limitation for emails from specific addresses

Tags: exchange

Is there a way so that exchange will always recieve emails in employee inboxes from predefined local email addresses even when the inbox is full, but without changing the inbox size?

For example, the employee's inbox is full, the office needs to send an important email that if not received the employee might have a loophole to not do the job. I have noticed that some employee keep their inboxes full in purpose to avoid such emails, especially that my field of work does not require the employee to attend to office.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hah. Give them all 100Gb of storage, that’ll show ‘em. Let’s see then try to fill that up. I mean seriously, email storage issues are so 2010. If that doesn’t stop ‘em, turn on your data retention rules and start deleting their emails from 10 years ago.